# Problem with node shape (diamond)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I am drawing a flow chart. Diamond-shaped nodes don't come out right. My minimal working example is below. There are no problems with ShareLaTeX, but it doesn't work on my computer.

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, fit}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=2cm, draw=black, inner sep=1pt, fill=green!10]
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,text width=5cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{endloop} = [ellipse, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, inner sep=1pt]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} [node distance=2cm]

        \node [input, name=input] {};
        \node(dec1)[decision, below of=input]{$Round <= Limit$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output on my computer:**

[image: with TeXstudio]

**Output from ShareLaTeX:**

[image: with sharelatex]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarise yourself further with our format. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Sorry and thanks. Error message for Texstudio is : Undefined control sequence. ...ision, below of=input]{$Round <= Limit$};

Comment: see my answer on question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300759/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- i can't reproduce your problem, after completing your mwe, it works fine
- you use one old definition (with obsolete `tizstyle` syntax) of nodes style for flow charts. i suggest to renew it as is used in mwe below (copied from my [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300759/write-easily-a-tikz-flowchart/300829#300829)):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
                tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                quotes,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 8mm and 16mm,
      start chain = A going below,
      base/.style = {draw, minimum width=32mm, minimum height=8mm,
                     align=center, on chain=A},
 startstop/.style = {base, rectangle, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
   process/.style = {base, rectangle, fill=orange!30},
        io/.style = {base, trapezium,
                     trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                     fill=blue!30},
  decision/.style = {base, diamond, fill=green!30},
  every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right}]
                    ]
\node (dec1) [decision] {$Round <= Limit$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- in the case, that you like to have flowchart's nodes style in preamble (for more flowcharts, than you can do this on the following way:

  ```
  \documentclass[border=3mm,
                  tikz]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                  calc, chains,
                  quotes,
                  positioning,
                  shapes.geometric}

  \tikzset{FlowChart/.style={     % <---
        start chain = A going below,
        base/.style = {draw, minimum width=32mm, minimum height=8mm,
                       align=center, on chain=A},
   startstop/.style = {base, rectangle, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
     process/.style = {base, rectangle, fill=orange!30},
          io/.style = {base, trapezium,
                       trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                       fill=blue!30},
    decision/.style = {base, diamond, fill=green!30},
    every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right}
                          }% end of FlowChart styles
    }


  \begin{document}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,  % <---
      node distance = 8mm and 16mm,
                      ]
  \node(dec1)[decision]{$Round <= Limit$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```
- *note*: i don't see any befits for declaring nodes as coordinates (for input and output). for this purposes you can simply use `\coordinate`, if you really need it.
- an example of code for relatively simple flowchart you can find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300759/write-easily-a-tikz-flowchart/300829#300829).

**addendum:**

- above document examples also works with any other document class, not only with `standalone`. for example:

  ```
  \documentclass[ pdftex, oneside,    
                  Einseitiger Druck. 12pt,    
                  Schriftgroesse parskip=half,    
                  topmargin = 10pt,   headheight = 33pt,  headsepline,    footsepline,    
                  footheight = 16pt,  abstracton, DIV=calc,   
                  Satzspiegel berechnen BCOR=8mm, headinclude=false, footinclude=false, listof=totoc, toc=bibliography,   
                  ]{scrreprt}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                  calc, chains,
                  quotes,
                  positioning,
                  shapes.geometric}

  \tikzset{FlowChart/.style={     % <---
        start chain = A going below,
        base/.style = {draw, minimum width=32mm, minimum height=8mm,
                       align=center, on chain=A},
   startstop/.style = {base, rectangle, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
     process/.style = {base, rectangle, fill=orange!30},
          io/.style = {base, trapezium,
                       trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                       fill=blue!30},
    decision/.style = {base, diamond, fill=green!30},
    every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right}
                          }% end of FlowChart styles
    }

  \begin{document}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,  % <---
      node distance = 8mm and 16mm,
                      ]
  \node(dec1)[decision]{$Round <= Limit$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

gives the same result as both mwe before.

Comment: hmm, if I start a new project, your example works. But when I add exact the same think at my actual project: Undefined control sequence. \node (dec1) [decision] {$Round <= Limit$};

Comment: @Aaron, this means that your actual project is corrupted (probably it has missing `tikz` libraries, etc. without knowing its preamble, i can't say what is going wrong  in your document (sorry, my crystal ball is on vacation :-( ).

Comment: I searched a little bit and I think it is because I have another class.{\documentclass[%
    pdftex,
    oneside,   % Einseitiger Druck.
    12pt,    % Schriftgroesse
    parskip=half, 
    %topmargin = 10pt, 
    headheight = 33pt, 
    headsepline,  
    footsepline,  
    %footheight = 16pt, 
    abstracton,
    DIV=calc,  % Satzspiegel berechnen
    BCOR=8mm,  
    headinclude=false,
    footinclude=false,
    listof=totoc,
    toc=bibliography, 
]{scrreprt}

Comment: I think your example is working because of the {standalone} environment.

Comment: no, it also work with any other document class. you only need to add package `tikz`, which is in my mwe included in option of `standalone`. please, edit your question and add your code in comment to your code snippet.

Comment: @Aaron, see addendum to my answer, which prove my claims in above comment.

Comment: problem was the predefined package includes from the university template: %\usepackage{additionalPackages/tikz-uml} % UML Diagramme
%\usepackage[european]{additionalPackages/circuitikz} after commenting it, it worked !

Comment: if you like to have further help, please consider my advice above: edit your question and add to your code example (which is not complete) complete preamble of your document. if answer as is solve preamble, please consider to accept it (by clicking on check mark on the top left side of answer.