# Help Required - regarding Arrows in flowchart

Tags: tikz-arrows, flow-charts

[image]

Can anyone help me with the code required to draw this?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496683/ to which your question seems to be duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here's one way to do it with just nodes and arrows manually setting the sizes of all boxes.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[minimum width=4cm, minimum height=2cm, draw] (A) at (0, 0) {};
        \node[minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, draw] (B) at ($(A) + (0, -3)$) {};
        % Note 1.41 ~= sqrt(2)
        \node[minimum width=1.41*2cm, minimum height=1.41*2cm, rotate=45, draw] (C) at ($(B) + (0, -4)$) {};
        \draw[->] ($(A.north) + (0, 1)$) -- (A.north);
        \draw[->] (A.south) -- (B.north);
        \draw[->] (B.south) -- (C.north east);
        \draw[->] (C.south west) -- ($(C.south west) + (0, -1)$);
        \coordinate (D) at (-3, 0);
        \draw[->] (C.north west) -- (C.north west -| D) -- (A.west -| D) -- (A.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: suggest to add the text `no` left of the feedback arrow

Comment: You can add text to an arrow using something like `\draw (A) -- (B) node[midway, left] {text};`. There are plenty of questions and answers to this effect on the site.