# coding the arrow's path in flowchart

Tags: tikz-arrows, flow-charts

I made some changes to Zarko's code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300759/write-easily-a-tikz-flowchart/300829) to make my own flowchart.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
% shapes
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
%arrows
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
%decorations
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,decorations.pathreplacing,patterns,shadows.blur,fadings}
% miscellaneous
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,positioning,fpu,angles,fit,spy,chains}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 8mm and 16mm,
  start chain = A going below,
  base/.style = {draw, minimum width=32mm, minimum height=8mm,
    align=center, on chain=A},
  startstop/.style = {ultra thick,double,base, rectangle, rounded corners, fill=white},
  process/.style = {ultra thick,base, rectangle, fill=white},
  io/.style = {ultra thick,base, trapezium, 
    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
    fill=white},
  decision/.style = {ultra thick,base, diamond, fill=white},
  every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right}]
  ]
  \node [startstop]       {Έναρξη};     % <-- A-1
  \node [io]              {Εισαγωγή}; %A-2
  \node [decision]        {Ερώτηση}; %Α-3
  \node [io]              {Απάντηση}; %A-4
  \node [startstop]       {Τέλος};      % <-- A-5
  \node [process, right=of A-3]    {Κάτι};     % <-- A-6

  \draw [arrows=-Stealth] 
  (A-1) edge          (A-2)
  (A-2) edge   (A-3)
  (A-3) edge  ["όχι"]     (A-4)
    (A-3) edge  ["ναι"]     (A-6)
  (A-4) edge    (A-5)
  (A-6) |- ($(A-1.south east)!0.5!(A-2.north east)$)
  -| ([xshift=7mm] A-2.north)
  ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like.

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to draw the arrow from `A-3` (diamond "Ερώτηση") to `A-2` (parallelogram "Εισαγωγή") without the `A-6` (rectangle "Κάτι"). **I want something like this:**

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: @Zarko , no they are not. At the 2nd is missing the rectangle "Κάτι". That's what I want.

Comment: you are right, I was "blind". See answer below ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified as little as possible your code by doing:

1. I added the `every join/.style=-Stealth` option that automatically draws the arrows without having to rebuild the chain.
2. I placed the node A-6 at the top right of the node A-2 without joining it to the chain, without tracing it and transforming it into a coordinate.

   `\node [on chain,coordinate, above right=3mm and 20 mm of A-2]{};     % <-- A-6`
3. Thus, I build an arrow for the loop because (A-6) is not joined to the chain.
   `\draw [arrows=-Stealth] (A-3) -| node[pos=.25,below]{Κάτι}(A-6)-| (A-2.30);`
4. I only place the label without drawing anything more since the arrows have already been built by the chain.
   `\path  (A-3) --node[left]{όχι} (A-4);`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[greek]{babel}

% babel dont work for me, i took these 5 lines from the answer of Zarko
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setromanfont{Minion Pro} %% Select your favourite font
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{tikz}
% shapes
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
%arrows
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
%decorations
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,decorations.pathreplacing,patterns,shadows.blur,fadings}
% miscellaneous
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,positioning,fpu,angles,fit,spy,chains}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 8mm and 16mm,
  start chain = A going below,
  base/.style = {draw, minimum width=32mm, minimum height=8mm,
    align=center, on chain=A,join},
  startstop/.style = {ultra thick,double,base, rectangle, rounded corners, fill=white},
  process/.style = {ultra thick,base, rectangle, fill=white},
  io/.style = {ultra thick,base, trapezium, 
    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
    fill=white},
  decision/.style = {ultra thick,base, diamond, fill=white},
  every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right},
  every join/.style=-Stealth]
  ]
  \node [startstop]       {Έναρξη};     % <-- A-1
  \node [io]              {Εισαγωγή}; %A-2
  \node [decision]        {Ερώτηση}; %Α-3
  \node [io]              {Απάντηση}; %A-4
  \node [startstop]       {Τέλος};      % <-- A-5
  \node [on chain,coordinate, above right=3mm and 20 mm of A-2]{};     % <-- A-6

  \draw [arrows=-Stealth] 
  (A-3) -| node[pos=.25,below]{Κάτι}(A-6)-| (A-2.30);
  \draw  (A-3) --node[left]{όχι} (A-4);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank's a lot! Problem solved. I have only one more question. Is it possible to change `3mm and 20 mm`? If I change the size of the book or of the font, maybe this causes a problem. Or not? Is it possible to put it automatically at the middle of `A-1` and `A-2`? Thank's!

Comment: What do you mean by the middle of (A-1) and (A-3)? Do you want the arrow (A-2) to (A-3) and the end of the loop to merge?

Comment: I wanted exactly what you write, but with other coding at the part of this that I highlight (https://ibb.co/RcrpmNP). I wanted this line automatically at the middle of `A-1` scheme and `A-2` scheme (without `3mm and 20 mm`) so, if I change something to the book, the result will be the same. But never mind. It's nor really important.

Comment: The point where the arrow ends is the one defined by `(A-2.30)`. If you write `(A-2)`, the two arrows merge: `\draw [arrows=-Stealth] (A-3) -| node[pos=.25,below]{Κάτι}(A-6.center)-| (A-2);`

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 5):

You only need to remove node "A-6" and draw arrow from `A-3` to `A-2`. I also took opportunity in rearrange loading `tikz` libraries and a little bit simplified/ shortened code for image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setromanfont{Minion Pro} %% Select your favorite font
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows, arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                decorations.text, decorations.pathreplacing,
                fadings, fit, 
                patterns, positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes, shadows.blur,
                spy}

\begin{document}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 4mm,
  start chain = A going below,
  base/.style = {draw, minimum width=32mm, minimum height=8mm,
                  align=center, on chain=A, join=by -Stealth},
startstop/.style = {ultra thick,double,base, rectangle, rounded corners, fill=white},
  process/.style = {ultra thick,base, rectangle, fill=white},
    io/.style = {trapezium, trapezium stretches,
                 trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,       
                 base, ultra thick, fill=white},
  decision/.style = {ultra thick,base, diamond, fill=white},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right}
                        ]
  \node [startstop]       {Έναρξη};     % <-- A-1
  \node [io]              {Εισαγωγή};  
  \node [decision]        {Ερώτηση};  
  \node [io]              {Απάντηση};  
  \node [startstop]       {Τέλος};      % <-- A-5

\coordinate[above left=of A-2.east] (aux);
\draw [arrows=-Stealth]
        (A-3.east)  to  ["ναι"] ++ (1,0) |- (aux) -- (aux |- A-2.north);
\path   (A-3)       to  ["όχι"]     (A-4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 1:** compiled by XeLaTeX engine.

**Edit 2:** from all libraries in your MWE are actually used only the following:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes
                }
```

Comment: thank's for your answer! It was too difficult to choose between AndréC's and your code. So I try some changes at these codes. The **1st** problem I had with your code was *"όχι"* witch printed on the parallelogram (https://pastebin.com/y9wxeMaZ). The **2nd** problem was with the position of the loop's arrow (https://pastebin.com/74RDfuN5). Maybe the problem was `pdflatex` that I used. For these reasons I preferred AndréC's code (even I didn't like `3mm and 20 mm`), that I can change it more easily (for my latex's knowledge). Thank's again for the starting idea and for your answers!

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας, it is up to you what you like to have. I do not need any explanation why you decides as you. Al other, if is problem, please ask new question. I'm very convinced, that my code is better than selected by you.

Comment: obviously your code is better than selected by me. I give my explanation for your time that you spend for my question. Thank's again!